# Recovering from maximum unsampled reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When trying to create a new unsampled report through the GA API, all of our requests (to insert) receive an HTTP 400 with this in the response:

"Error creating this entity. You have reached the maximum allowed entities of this type."

It appears there isn't a way to delete unsampled reports, and I've not had luck finding a documented maximum number of reports. Is there any way to either work around that limit or delete older unsampled reports?